# CORS Request - Terminal Works, Browser Fails

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to fetch an image via ajax from an amazon server. That server is configured to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

The issue is that when I do the request from terminal, I see the response fine.

But when I do the AJAX request from browser, I'm blocked and I don't see that header on the response.

Terminal request:

```
➜  ~  curl -sI -H "Origin: google.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" http://my-domain/my-image.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 595284
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:28:02 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Hydrangeas.jpg"
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 07:00:21 GMT
x-amz-version-id: null
ETag: "bdf3bf1da3405725be763540d6601144"
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 4132
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 b7b782c917cd62c6605a1684c071a774.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 7t1gB74LHHWEIXcl_ml6pWC9voDrfSakCMUJ2KeAjMYZ-37aZYmPcg==
```

When I try from Chrome/FF (haven't tried others), I see the canonical error message and when I look in the network tab I don't see the ACAA header:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ***. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '***' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is the code I use to try and get the image:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
         // never gets here, status is always 0 from the block
     }
}
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This one could be a simple mistake - are you 100% sure that the URI you use in JavaScript is the same one you used in terminal? Apparently the browser says that there's no such header present, but terminal shows it is. The only logical conclusion is that your browser is not requesting the same resource or you might be behind a proxy that removes the header?

Comment: Unfortunately the URI is the same one (copy pasted several times to make sure). The option of the proxy removing the header is interesting, I'll look into that, thanks.